# Check response type from MVC web api in unit tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having a brain freeze.

The response I am getting back from a web api post is;

```
<string>985c4198-8892-4738-8f85-d9adf5ff474a</string>
```

which is sent back using;

```
return myGuid.ToString();
```

I want to be able to unit test the response, but for the life of me cannot think of how to do it. I need to be able to check that it is a Guid. I believe I am missing a step to 'deserialize' the response into a `typeof(string)` and then I can `TryParse()`, but this is where my mind is going wrong tonight.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be testing calls to the web api. You should unit test the logic within the web api, and you can also test the calling code by faking the calls to the web api, but imho you shouldn't be testing actual calls. That's an integration test, not a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Guid g = Guid.Empty();

string webApiResult = GetApiResult();

webApiResult = webApiResult.Replace("<string>", string.Empty);
webApiResult = webApiResult.Replace("</string>", string.Empty);

Assert.IsTrue(Guid.TryParse(webApiResult , out g));
```

The key is to use TryParse which will return a boolean indicating whether parsing was successful.

Comment: That's the thing, the response will fail a TryParse as it is not a guid, it;s a guid wrapped in <string></string>. Also you can't create a null guid.

Comment: Ahhh, OK. In that case it looks like you could simply trim away the <string> and </string> portions, leaving just the GUID section, which you can then use for the TryParse.